# How to assign a value to a class vairable from inside a block?

Tags: swift

I am trying to set a value to a class variable from inside a block. But the value is not being set for some reason. To be frank I don't really know how to set value to a class variable from inside a block, so any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
class PhoneAuthViewController: UIViewController {
var verificationID: String = ""

@IBAction func activateButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var phoneNumberString = ""
        if phoneNumberField.text != nil {
            phoneNumberString = phoneNumberField.text!
        } else {
            phoneNumberString = ""
        }
        //Checking if the phone number is in the right format
        let phoneNumberFormatStatus = checkPhoneNumberFormat(phoneNumberData: phoneNumberString)
        if (phoneNumberFormatStatus != true) {
            //Showing the alert if the user enters invalid phone number
            showInvalidPhoneNumberAlert(phoneNumberData: phoneNumberString)
        }
        verifyPhoneWithFireBase(phoneNumberData: phoneNumberString)
    }


func verifyPhoneWithFireBase(phoneNumberData: String) {
    PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumberData, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in
        if (verificationID != nil) {
            self.verificationID = verificationID!
        }
        if let error = error {
            self.showAlert(errorString: error.localizedDescription)
            return
        } else {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "otpVerificationScreen", sender: self.activateButton)
        }
    }
}
@IBAction func verifyOtp(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("\(self.verificationID) is self.verificationID")
        print("\(verificationID) is verificationID")
    }
   }
```

The function verifyOtp doesn't print anything.

Comment: Show how and when you call `verifyPhoneWithFireBase` and how and when you call `verifyOtp`. And keep in mind that `verifyPhoneWithFireBase` is run asynchronously.

Comment: verifyOtp is an action connected to a button. The other one is called from another function(activateButtonPressed) which is an action of another button. If its run asynchronously, what do I do to know when the execution is finished?

Comment: when do you click verifyOtp directly after clicking activateButtonPressed ??

Comment: After tapping on the activate button, I have to solve a captcha challenge. I enter the OTP and tap on verifyOtp aafter that.